# how to make the fixed content with position(x,y)on the canvas responsive with mobile device? using h5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, responsive, responsive-images

i use something below to make my canvas responsive, and it is accutlly works fine but only for the image that draw on the canvas, the problem is that i also added some slot on the canvas as condition to tell if the mouseclick on the right place(use addeventlisenter('click')).after scale the canvas all this slot become doesn't work, anyone can give some suggestion on how to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance.
for example:i set a slot[x:185,y:290,w:70,h:70], if the mouseclick in the slot, it will trigger some other event,but after make the canvas responsive, this function doesn't work.

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
function resizecanvas(){
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var ratio = c.width / c.height;
    var width = height * ratio;
    c.style.width = width + 'px';
    c.style.height = height + 'px';
}
window.addEventListener('load',resizecanvas,false);
window.addEventListener('resize', resizecanvas, false);
```

Comment: You need to use fractions. Instead of `x: 185` use `x: width * 0.4`. And so on.

Comment: You can wrap your canvas inside div and handle the click event from that div.